# Why is my lock screen upside down

Tags: settings

I had issues with my screen rotating until I turned off auto rotation but for some reason when I go to my lock screen it is upside down.  I am using a Samsung Chromebook Pro with and Intel CORE m3 processor.

Comment: Does it have. A touch screen?

Comment: Yes it does.  I really like the look of this OS and really want to adopt it but it still seems to be a bit buggy.  Thinking about Linux Mint if I can't get issues resolved with this one.

Comment: Hrm, I'm pretty sure they're a bootflag for the kennel to disable the rotation sensor which will prevent it from turning like that. I'll try and see if I can find the link